# Cursor parameters and aggregating results

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I have the following cursor declaration:

```
CURSOR c_2800s(map_code VARCHAR2,serv_code VARCHAR2,sub_serv_code         VARCHAR2,bill_to_datetime VARCHAR2) IS
SELECT DISTINCT kndtctc.tctc_cncclipu,TCTC_CNCTAEJE,TCTC_CNNETNAM,nvl(TEXE_CNASUPRO,0000000000),nvl(TEXE_CNNETNAM,00) 
FROM KNDTSCM, KNDTCTC, KNDTEXE
WHERE trim(TSCM_CNMAPCO) = map_code
AND KNDTSCM.TSCM_CNCONTRA = kndtctc.tctc_cncclipu
AND KNDTCTC.TCTC_CNTIPCLI = 'C'  -- FOR H2H --
AND KNDTCTC.TCTC_CNESTADO IN ('01','03')
AND kndtctc.tctc_cncclipu = kndtexe.texe_cncclipu 
AND kndtexe.texe_cnestado in ('01','03')
AND KNDTSCM.TSCM_CNESTADO IN ('01','03')
AND trim(kndtscm.tscm_cnservic) = trim(kndtexe.texe_cnfuncid)
AND trim(kndtscm.tscm_cnsubser) = trim(kndtexe.texe_cnsubser)
AND trim(KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNFUNCID) = serv_code
AND  trim(kndtexe.texe_cnsubser) = sub_serv_code;
```

For any serv_code, there can be multiple subserv_code(I1-I8) and map_code(1009, 1010, etc). The procedure uses this cursor to add up file transmission volume for a customer. It is an existing SP and when it was originally written it did not have to account for multiple choices on the above mentioned. I need to change it minimally such as to account for those multiple options that are now available. The opening of the cursor is below(i added which will not work since i need just one output based on the query returning the volume per account(texe_cnasupro):

```
IF(r_input_billing.r_bill_srvc_code=2806) THEN
OPENc_2800s_mnthy_mntce
('1224','3050','I2',r_input_billing.r_billing_to_datetime);
LOOP
FETCH c_2800s_mnthy_mntce INTO R_INFORPT_RECORD;
EXIT WHEN c_2800s_mnthy_mntce%NOTFOUND;
r_cnt:=r_cnt+1;
dbms_output.put_line('Master Account:'||R_INFORPT_RECORD.r_master_acct);
dbms_output.put_line('Account:'||R_INFORPT_RECORD.r_acct);
dbms_output.put_line('Bank ID:'||R_INFORPT_RECORD.r_bnk_id);
-- Write this line to the output file --
UTL_FILE.PUTF(output_file_handle,r_input_billing.r_bill_srvc_code||'|'||r_input_billing.r_billing_from_datetime||'|'||r_input_billing.r_billing_to_datetime||'|'||r_input_billing.r_frequency||'|'||to_char(R_INFORPT_RECORD.r_master_acct,'FM0000000000')||'|'||to_char(R_INFORPT_RECORD.r_master_bnk_id,'FM00')||'|'||to_char(R_INFORPT_RECORD.r_acct,'FM0000000000')||'|'||to_char(trim(R_INFORPT_RECORD.r_bnk_id),'FM00')||'|00000000000000001|'||systimestamp||'|\n' );                      
END LOOP;
CLOSE c_2800s_mnthy_mntce;

ELSIF(r_input_billing.r_bill_srvc_code=2806) THEN
OPEN c_2800s_mnthy_mntce
('1224','3050','I6',r_input_billing.r_billing_to_datetime); 
LOOP
FETCH c_2800s_mnthy_mntce INTO R_INFORPT_RECORD;
EXIT WHEN c_2800s_mnthy_mntce%NOTFOUND;
r_cnt:=r_cnt+1;
dbms_output.put_line('Master Account:'||R_INFORPT_RECORD.r_master_acct);
dbms_output.put_line('Account:'||R_INFORPT_RECORD.r_acct);
dbms_output.put_line('Bank ID:'||R_INFORPT_RECORD.r_bnk_id);
-- Write this line to the output file --
UTL_FILE.PUTF(output_file_handle,r_input_billing.r_bill_srvc_code||'|'||r_input_billing.r_billing_from_datetime||'|'||r_input_billing.r_billing_to_datetime||'|'||r_input_billing.r_frequency||'|'||to_char(R_INFORPT_RECORD.r_master_acct,'FM0000000000')||'|'||to_char(R_INFORPT_RECORD.r_master_bnk_id,'FM00')||'|'||to_char(R_INFORPT_RECORD.r_acct,'FM0000000000')||'|'||to_char(trim(R_INFORPT_RECORD.r_bnk_id),'FM00')||'|00000000000000001|'||systimestamp||'|\n' );                      
END LOOP;
CLOSE c_2800s_mnthy_mntce;
```

I need help aggregating results for the cursor to achieve the desired results(without messing up what already exists, the cursor above is used for a multitude of other serv_codes/map_codes already in use today) i have mentioned above. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You could try making subserv_code and map_code tables of values and join them as tables into your cursor instead of passing them as parameters to the cursor:

```
-- Use an appropropriate data type for SUB_SERV_CODE
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SUB_SERV_CODE_T AS OBJECT (SUB_SERV_CODE VARCHAR2(30));
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SUB_SERV_CODE_TT AS TABLE OF SUB_SERV_CODE_T;
/

-- Use an appropropriate data type for MAP_CODE
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MAP_CODE_T AS OBJECT (MAP_CODE VARCHAR2(30));
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MAP_CODE_TT AS TABLE OF MAP_CODE_T;
/


DECLARE
  -- Table variables passed in the cursor parameters can't
  -- be used in the from clause.  Intead they must be
  -- declared and in scope before the cursor is declared.
  sub_serv_code SUB_SERV_CODE_TT;
  map_code MAP_CODE_TT;

  CURSOR c_2800s( serv_code VARCHAR2
                , bill_to_datetime VARCHAR2 )
  IS
   SELECT DISTINCT kndtctc.tctc_cncclipu
        , TCTC_CNCTAEJE
        , TCTC_CNNETNAM
        , NVL( TEXE_CNASUPRO, 0000000000 )
        , NVL( TEXE_CNNETNAM, 00 )
     FROM KNDTSCM
     JOIN KNDTCTC
       ON KNDTCTC.TCTC_CNCCLIPU = KNDTSCM.TSCM_CNCONTRA
     JOIN KNDTEXE
       ON KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNCCLIPU = KNDTCTC.TCTC_CNCCLIPU
     JOIN TABLE(map_code)
       ON TRIM( TSCM_CNMAPCO ) = map_code.map_code
     JOIN TABLE(sub_serv_code)
       ON trim( kndtexe.texe_cnsubser ) = sub_serv_code.sub_serv_code
    WHERE KNDTCTC.TCTC_CNTIPCLI         = 'C' -- FOR H2H --
      AND KNDTCTC.TCTC_CNESTADO        IN( '01', '03' )
      AND kndtexe.texe_cnestado        IN( '01', '03' )
      AND KNDTSCM.TSCM_CNESTADO        IN( '01', '03' )
      AND trim( kndtscm.tscm_cnservic ) = trim( kndtexe.texe_cnfuncid )
      AND trim( kndtscm.tscm_cnsubser ) = trim( kndtexe.texe_cnsubser )
      AND trim( KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNFUNCID ) = serv_code;

  R_INFORPT_RECORD  c_2800s%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  -- One method to initialize a table variable
  sub_serv_code := SUB_SERV_CODE_TT();
  sub_serv_code.extend(8);
  sub_serv_code(1) := sub_serv_code_t('I1');
  sub_serv_code(2) := sub_serv_code_t('I2');
  sub_serv_code(3) := sub_serv_code_t('I3');
  sub_serv_code(4) := sub_serv_code_t('I4');
  sub_serv_code(5) := sub_serv_code_t('I5');
  sub_serv_code(6) := sub_serv_code_t('I6');
  sub_serv_code(7) := sub_serv_code_t('I7');
  sub_serv_code(8) := sub_serv_code_t('I8');

  -- Another method to initialze a table variable
  with t1(map_code) as (
    select '1009' from dual union all
    select '1010' from dual
  ) select MAP_CODE_T(map_code)
      bulk collect into map_code
      from t1;

  -- You'll need to fix the open cursor call
  OPEN c_2800s('3050','r_input_billing.r_billing_datetime');
  LOOP
    FETCH c_2800s into R_INFORPT_RECORD;
    exit when c_2800s%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(R_INFORPT_RECORD.sub_serv_code);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_2800s;
END;
/
```

Not having access to your tables, this is the sample cursor I used for testing in place of the one shown above:

```
  CURSOR c_2800s( serv_code VARCHAR2
                , bill_to_datetime VARCHAR2 )
  IS
   SELECT SUB_SERV_CODE FROM TABLE(sub_serv_code);
```